# Trigger(like) event in MySQL calculating values from current and previous row

Tags: mysql, triggers, tableview, calculated-columns

I have a mysql database table in which some raw metrics data is being stored concerning total number of commits on a different (web)services. It looks like this:

```
ID,  timestamp,                Service_name, Commits,  TPS  
001, 2014-03-10  09:00:00,     serviceA,     1000  
002, 2014-03-10  09:00:00,     serviceB,     1300    
003, 2014-03-10  09:00:30,     serviceA,     1800  
004, 2014-03-10  09:00:30,     serviceB,     1700
```

The last column (avg transactions/second) is not yet populated. What I want to accomplish is that the values in this column are calculated upon insertion of a snapshot of different service commits (all with same timestamp).

The calculation would be: (serviceX commits current insert - serviceX commits previous insert) / (serviceX timestamp current insert - serviceX timestamp previous insert).

In the end I want to plot the calculated TPS per service in a pChart (already working when filling in TPS myself!)

I did some researching about: triggering, calculating/computing columns and maybe even creating a new database view. However I'm unsure about how to procede next and I hope that some of you can point me in the right direction.

The database is used solely for presenting these service metrics on a monitor screen so it's not  used for anything else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what would be the TPS for record 1?

Comment: Would be so easy to do in a single query (without triggers or similar workaround) if only MySQL supported modern SQL features.

Comment: The TPS for service A at 09:00:30 would be: (1800-1000)/(09:00:30 - 09:00:00) = 26.67. For service B the TPS at 09:00:30 is calculated in a simular manner resulting in (1700-1300)/30 = 13.3.

Comment: yes, but what about record 1? should it be 0? does my answer below satisfy you or do you need more details?

Answer (score 0):

coif you are sure about the order of insertion, then you can use a trigger (before insert), where you:

a) select the row for the last service
b) update NEW.TPS with the computation

The trigger is the better option because that column is only computed once (no need for updates/recomputation).